# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is quite odd. But my contact form is malfunctioning. I have implemented quite a number of these forms and it defies my reasoning why am getting `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` on this line

```
<%= form_for(@inquiry, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'}) do |f| %>
```

Here is the view;

```
        <%= form_for(@inquiry, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'}) do |f| %>          
            <%= f.hidden_field :nickname, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => ""}  %>
            <div class="block clearfix" >
                <%= f.label :name, "Name", class: "col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right" %>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'col-xs-12' %>
                </div>
            </div><!--//form-group-->
            <div class="space-4"></div> 
            <div class="block clearfix" >
                <%= f.label :email, "Email", class: 'col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right' %>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'col-xs-12' %>
                </div>
            </div><!--//form-group-->  
            <div class="space-4"></div>         
             <div class="block clearfix">                   
                <%= f.label :subject, "Subject",class: "col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right" %>        
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "col-xs-12"   %>  
                </div> 
            </div><!--//form-group--> 
            <div class="space-4"></div>                             
             <div class="block clearfix">                   
                <%= f.label :message, "Message",class: "col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right" %>                    
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <%= f.text_area :message, class: "col-xs-12", :"parsley-maxlength"=>"1000"  %>
                </div>
            </div><!--//form-group-->                                                           
            <%= f.hidden_field :check  %>                   
            <div class="form-actions clearfix">
                <%= f.submit  "Send", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-12" %> 
            </div>    
        <% end %>
```

and controller;

```
  def new
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @inquiry }
    end
  end


  # POST /inquiries
  # POST /inquiries.json
  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @inquiry.deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @inquiry, notice: 'We will be in touch as soon as possible. Thank you!' }
        format.json { render json: @inquiry, status: :created, location: @inquiry }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @inquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the model;

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper


  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone_number, :message, :nickname, :subject, :check

  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/ }

  validates :message, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 1000 }

  validates :nickname,  format: { with: /^$/ }

  validates :subject, presence: true, length: {maximum: 25}

  validates :check, presence: false

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def deliver
    ContactUs.contact_us(name, email, subject, message).deliver
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end  
end
```

Comment: Just curious.Why are you having `@inquiry.deliver`? Isn't should be `@inquiry.save` ?

Comment: What are your params set to when it fails?  It looks like params[:inquiry] is null.

Comment: @Pavan, deliver is for sending mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the contact form issue by changing;

```
<%= form_for(@inquiry, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'}) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for :inquiry, url: inquiries_path, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |f| %>
```

and the changed the controller to ;

```
class InquiriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new
  end

  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])

    if @inquiry.deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Your inquiry has been sent and we will be in touch as soon as possible. Thank you!"
      redirect_to action: :new
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Your inquiry has not been sent Thank you!"
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<%= form_for @inquiry, :html => {:data-validate => 'parsley'} do |f| %>
OR
<%= form_for @inquiry, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Does not really help. The problem is with `@inquiry` in relation to the controller and model